# Timeout for Futures in Akka

Tags: timeout, future, akka

We have a server that processes portfolio and securities (inside it) in different actors. For portfolio with smaller number of securities (<20) this works fine. When i increase the number of security count to 1000, encountered following issues:

akka.dispatch.FutureTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000] milliseconds

I could bypass this error by increasing timeout inside akka config, is that the right thing to do? In akka versions earlier than 1.2 i could set self.timeout inside the actor but that is deprecated.

The other issue I faced (intermittently) is that the entire server hangs while joining in futures.map code inside my portfolio actor:

```
    //fork out for each security
    val listOfFutures = new ListBuffer[Future[Security]]()
    for (security <- portfolio.getSecurities.toList) {
      val securityProcessor = actorOf[SecurityProcessor].start()
      listOfFutures += (securityProcessor ? security) map {
        _.asInstanceOf[Security]
      }
    }
    EventHandler.info(this,"joining results from security processors")
    //join for each security
    val futures = Future.sequence(listOfFutures.toList)
    futures.map {
      listOfSecurities =>
        portfolioResponse = MergeHelper.merge(portfolio, listOfSecurities)
    }.get
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not state which version of Akka you're on, and given my limited time with the crystal ball I'll assume that you're on 1.2.

You can specify a Timeout when you call ask/?

(Also, your code is a bit convoluted, but that I have already solved in your other question.)

Cheers,
√

Comment: correct. Akka 1.2 The server gets stuck on following line. so to debug I had to split: val futureResult = Future.sequence(                   portfolio.getSecurities.toList map { security => (actorOf[SecurityProcessor].start() ? security).mapTo[Security] }                 ) map { securities => MergeHelper.merge(portfolio, securities) }

Comment: Did specifying a longer timeout in the call to sequence and ? help?
You can also try 1.3-RC1, it's gotten some bugfixes as well.

Comment: longer timeout definitely helped with the Timeout error. ok will try 1.3 out. Thanks for the help, Viktor !

Comment: One thing that fixes my intermittent hang for sure is if i add the following to my Actor: self.dispatcher = Dispatchers.newExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher("SecurityProcessor")
    .withNewThreadPoolWithLinkedBlockingQueueWithCapacity(100)
    .setCorePoolSize(1)
    .setMaxPoolSize(2)
    .setKeepAliveTimeInMillis(60000)
    .setRejectionPolicy(new CallerRunsPolicy)
    .build

Comment: If you set that inside each actor, you create a new dispatcher for each actor, where maxPoolSize(2) doesn't make sense at all since an Actor can only ever run on one thread at a time.

Comment: You are correct that's why i can't use this, even though it eliminates the hanging issue.

Comment: Then you need to prolong the timeout. Did you try 1.3-RC1?

Comment: after 1.3-RC1 i can't replicate the hang (even without the EventDrivenDispatcher) line. Unless I get the hang again, treat this as mission accomplished :) Thanks again